# Ajax POST request 200 but Form is not valid

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

I am working to add comments and replies via Ajax and the POST.request is ok however the form itself is not valid hence no data is being saved in the DB. Please see below some of my code:
Views

```
def view_post(request, slug):
  post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
  comments = post.comments.filter(approved_comment=True, reply=None).order_by('-date_posted')
  form = CommentForm()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      comment = form.save(commit=False)
      reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
      data = None

      if reply_id:
        data = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)

      comment.author = request.user
      comment.post = post
      comment.reply = data
      comment.save()
    else:
      print('form not valid')

  else:
      form = CommentForm()

  context = {
    'post' : post,
    'comments' : comments,
    'form' : form
  }

  if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({ 'form' : html })

  return render(request, 'blog/post.html', context)
```

and here is the Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `/post/${slug}/`,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $(event.target).parents('.reply-form').hide()
      $('main-comment-section').html(response['form']);
      $('textarea').val('');
    },
    error: function(rs, e) {
      console.log(rs.responseText);
    },
  })
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

-update-

Thank you very much for your help, by printing the form.errors it helped me understand what was wrong. It had to do with the relationships in the models and a required field.

Comment: Where did you specify to return something different?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am sorry but I don't really understand what you are trying to say. Could you be a bit more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns 200 because you say to return 200. Indeed, you return:

```
return render(request, 'blog/post.html', context)
```

and a `render` will render the template and wrap it by a `HttpResponse` with by default `status = 200`.

You thus should return something different, for example a `JsonResponse` with `status=400`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def view_post(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.filter(
        approved_comment=True, reply=None
    ).order_by('-date_posted')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.instance.reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            form.save()
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'fail'}, status=400)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post' : post,
        'comments' : comments,
        'form' : form
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({ 'form' : html })
    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', context)
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct, however how do I solve this? Is something wrong with the form itself?

Comment: @Adrian0012: you can `print(form.errors)` in the (first) `else` clause, to display the errors of the form.